# SQL Server Inner join on UID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to do an inner join on 2 tables having same names, but in different databases (database A and B). The table is as below:

[image: Table]

My aim is to update columns MinMultiplyFactor and MaxMultipleFactor in the table in database A based on 2 conditions (NodeId and Year should match with the other table).

I wrote a query:

```
update DB_A.[dbo].[TABLE]
set DB_A.[dbo].[TABLE].MinMultiplyFactor = B.MinMultiplyFactor
FROM DB_A.[dbo].[TABLE] A INNER JOIN DB_B.[dbo].[TABLE] B
ON A.NodeId = B.NodeId
and A.Year = B.Year;
```

But it's saying 0 rows updated even when there are a lot of common Node Ids and years. The NodeId is a uniqueIdentifier in the table. May be that's the issue?

Comment: Unique identifiers are fine for joins.  My guess is that the columns do not really match.

Comment: Try a simple SELECT with JOIN and see what it returns. If it returns data, then turn it to an update. If not, it will be easier to debug the SELECT than an UPDATE.

Comment: How about Year Column. Are there common years for given NodeIds??

Comment: There are common NodeIds but I can't use them in a join with select also. And they behave weirdly in MS Excel too when I use vlookup. Don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I think there are no common NodeIds. Let me re-check :(

Comment: Yes, There is no common combination :( Sorry guys. and Thanks :)